# Is there any paper about stanford dependency parser improving?

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

Just as the title, I want to know whether there's any work(application or papers) on improving stanford dependency parser. I mean external research , not the version updates. And the improving aspects the papers involved(say speed, accuracy etc.)
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at a web search already? -- Edit: Doesn't seem so.

Comment: I mean external research , not the version updates.

Comment: That's not clear from your question. So, what _have_ you found out already?

Comment: Sorry for that, I only find this : http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/viterbiem.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes<sup>1,2</sup>.

---

- <sup>1</sup>: https://www.google.com/?q=stanford%20dependency%20parser
- <sup>2</sup>: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml:

> - Version 2.0.4   2012-11-12  Improved dependency code extraction efficiency, other dependency changes
> - Version 2.0.3     2012-07-09  Minor bug fixes
> - Version 2.0.2     2012-05-22  Some models now support training with extra tagged, non-tree data
> - Version 2.0.1     2012-03-09  Caseless English model included, bugfix for enforced tags
> - Version 2.0   2012-02-03  Threadsafe!
> - Version 1.6.9     2011-09-14  Improved recognition of imperatives, dependencies now explicitely include a root, parser knows osprey is a noun
> - Version 1.6.8     2011-06-19  New French model, improved foreign language models, bug fixes
> - Version 1.6.7     2011-05-15  Minor bug fixes.
> - Version 1.6.6     2011-04-20  Internal code and API changes (ArrayLists rather than Sentence; use of CoreLabel objects) to match tagger and CoreNLP.
> - Version 1.6.5     2010-11-30  Further improvements to English Stanford Dependencies and other minor changes
> - Version 1.6.4     2010-08-20  More minor bug fixes and improvements to English Stanford Dependencies and question parsing
> - Version 1.6.3     2010-07-09  Improvements to English Stanford Dependencies and question parsing, minor bug fixes
> - Version 1.6.2     2010-02-26  Improvements to Arabic parser models, and to English and Chinese Stanford Dependencies
> - Version 1.6.1     2008-10-26  Slightly improved Arabic and German parsing, and Stanford Dependencies
> - Version 1.6   2007-08-19  Added Arabic, k-best PCCFG parsing; improved English grammatical relations
> - Version 1.5.1     2006-06-11  Improved English and Chinese grammatical relations; fixed UTF-8 handling
> - Version 1.5   2005-07-21  Added grammatical relations output; fixed bugs introduced in 1.4
> - Version 1.4   2004-03-24  Made PCFG faster again (by FSA minimization); added German support
> - Version 1.3   2003-09-06  Made parser over twice as fast; added tokenization options
> - Version 1.2   2003-07-20  Halved PCFG memory usage; added support for Chinese
> - Version 1.1   2003-03-25  Improved parsing speed; included GUI, improved PCFG grammar
> - Version 1.0   2002-12-05  Initial release